# NaN type in GraphQL

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo

I need type Int or NaN, how can i make it?

```
union IntOrNaN = Int | NaN //Error

type house {
 address: String
 aprt: IntOrNaN
}
```

I tried unions but there isn't NaN type in GraphQl types

Comment: I'm not sure about graphql, but the **value** `NaN` is usually of type number; double or float or so. It's not a distinct type.

Comment: You cannot make a union between scalar types afaik.

Comment: What exactly do you need `NaN` for? Is `null` not enough? Or maybe you're looking for a graphql `Float`?

Comment: I need graphQL recognize my type as NaN or Int, in my database sometimes the field's value is NaN instead of Int type value.

Comment: @NareSakhoyan What database are you using? What exactly is the column type?

Comment: MongoDB, there the type is Int, but when I write Int in  graphQL there come's error that NaN can't be type of Int

Comment: You mean you've got a BSON 32-bit integer field in MongoDB? That cannot store `NaN`. It sounds like you should fix your resolver that somehow produces this vale that you don't want, instead of trying to change the GraphQL type. Can you post the resolver code, please? Do you actually *want* a `NaN` to be returned? What does it mean?